# Why a jQuery plug-in?

Tags: jquery, plugins

Given a jQuery Project (.html, .css, .js), is it a good idea to convert it to a jQuery Plug-In?

As a scientific researcher of many years, the 1st question I always ask is WHY? this or WHY? that.

I have developed a rather comprehensive jQuery Project. So ...

```
   (1) WHY? do I even want to convert it to a jQuery Plug-In?
   (2) IF there is a good reason, then HOW? do I do that conversion.
```

In my relatively un-informed mind, is a jQuery Plug-In just a drop-in module that someone can add to their Project with added options?

I literally don't know the answers, so I am looking to you folk!

Comment: You create a jQuery plugin if you have a general purpose tool that could be used by multiple applications.

Comment: You can find example of jQuery plugins here (and in many other places): https://www.creativebloq.com/jquery/top-jquery-plugins-6133175. What would your plugin "do"?

Comment: Jeromy - My current jQuery/vanilla javascript code expands the normally just-CSS driven drop menus to include jQuery/vanilla javascript to integrate hover + keypress events with the default CSS to travel from one menu item to another with particular emphasis on the visually impaired user. SO, I was thinking if I converted my NON-plug-in code to a Plug-in, others could integrate my added js code via drag-and-drop ... instead or manually copy and paste my js code.